# Create Desktop Shortcut to Network Connections Windows 8.1

Tags: shortcuts, windows-8.1

I'm trying to create a desktop shortcut that gets my right into the network connections screen on Windows 8.1. The way I get there now is basically Windows+R > ncpa.cpl  I don't mind doing that but I'm trying to set this up for someone that's more illiterate and needs shortcuts.

I've tried everything I can think of. The All Apps screen doesn't seem to have a shortcut to the network connections. If I search I can find it, but there are no right-click options to Send Shortcut to Desktop. I can't get any right click options to come up on any of the search results. If I go to the network connections and copy the path/URL at the top of the window, I can put that into a shortcut. It actually creates a shortcut that looks like it's going to work but when I click/double click on it, nothing happens.

What's the secret here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open the network connection windows, drag & drop the icon to the desktop:

[image]

this generates a shortcut. This works for several build in dialogs of Windows.